# Matlab Using .p file for compiling?

Tags: matlab, project, package, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I m working on a Matlab project and I need UsbWebcams package for capture image from webcam. I can run .m file in matlab but when I  compile project to create an exe file, My exe file return an error because usbWebcams package have some special .p files(Utility.p,webcamchannel.p etc) and I can not use these file for compiling.I searced on Internet and I didnt find any answer for this.  How can I use .p files in my project. I think there should be a solution and I should find it. Thanks for helping to all.

Comment: Are you sure?  Incorporating P-Code into the MATLAB Compiler has been available since R2009a: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95805-is-it-possible-for-matlab-compiler-for-generate-applications-that-use-p-code - If you can't, that means you're using a very old version of MATLAB but the link I provided has a suitable workaround.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know this answer and my problem is same with last answer in this link. I think compiler can not compile .p file of Usbwebcams, because of this my exe doesn't work correctly. If it can compile, my exe should work correctly because it works on matlab with run command. Maybe, it can be special situation for Usbwebcams package. By the way, I m using R2015a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although MATLAB Compiler should be able to compile `.p` files, it's possible that the `.p` files you're trying to compile may have dependencies that you can't see because they're p-coded. For example, they might call an external library (this is quite possible if they are for interfacing with a webcam), or they might call another function using `eval`.

Whether they're `.m` files or `.p` files, if the files you're trying to compile have a dependency of this sort you need to include it explicitly for the Compiler, otherwise it won't know where to find it. But if the file is p-coded, it's tough to find out what the dependencies might be. You might need to ask MathWorks directly for support in compiling this functionality.